# Why is my code is getting second row as header instead of first row

Tags: excel, vb.net

My code is getting second row records treating them as header while i want it to get first row records as hearder (code is skiping first row)

Note: am looping through columns

I have written my code to loop through an excel sheet to get headers of the sheet.It works fine but instead of getting the first row records,it skips and get the second row records
Note: am looping through columns

```
Dim path As String = txtPath.Text
Dim excel_connection As OleDbConnection
Dim dt As DataTable
Dim cmd As OleDbDataAdapter
'Dim sql As String
'Dim result As Boolean
Dim emp_type_id As String = ""
Dim branch_id As String = ""
Dim bank_id As String = ""
excel_connection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 Xml;")
cmd = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [sheet$]", excel_connection)
dt = New DataTable
cmd.Fill(dt)
For Each column As DataColumn In dt.Columns
    Dim columnName As String = dt.Rows(0)(column.ColumnName).ToString()
    If columnName = "" Then
    Else
        MsgBox(columnName)
    End If
Next
```

I want it to loop through the first row
Note: am looping through columns

Answer (score 0):

Try adding HDR=No into OleDbConnection Extended Properties. Like below:

```
excel_connection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=No;IMEX=1;';")
```

Comment: I tried to add "HDR=No" as advised. Now is giving me this error "Could not find installable ISAM"

Comment: You can try again with the edited  excel_connection

Comment: No problem. Please dont forget to tick as answered.